# tempnam() / mkstemp() like API operating on file descriptors?

Tags: files, posix

What race-free alternatives are there for the POSIX
functions of the `mkstemp(3)` / `tmpnam(3)` family?
The goal is of course to obtain a file name for
use with file descriptor APIs like `renameat2(2)`.

Ideally, there would be a companion to *mkstemp*, let’s call
it *mkstempat*, taking a directory file descriptor *dfd* as its
first argument, with *template* becoming the second argument
as a path relative to *dfd*.

Are there any widely available APIs for this, e. g. glib?

Comment: It would need more than one companion (`mkostempat`, `mkstempsat`, `mkostempsat`).  Also, just using `O_EXCL` (as `mkstemp` does) when creating files in other than the standard places is asking for trouble (`O_EXCL` is not supported on all filesystems)

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think there’s a *widely* available API for this. However Flatpak has an implementation of `mkstempat`, [`xdp_mkstempat`](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/blob/master/src/xdp-utils.c), licensed under the LGPL version 2 or later.

It looks like that is currently the only easily-available implementation of such a function... I suspect an argument could be made to get it added to glib, alongside glib’s existing `g_mkstemp` etc.